# How to translate vertex coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a vertex array defining a square with the following xyzw coordinates:

```
      -0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      -0.5, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.5, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
       0.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0
```

I want to translate it two units to the right so that the resulting array becomes:

```
      1.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      1.5, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      2.5, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
      2.5,  0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

I know I can achieve this by simply adding one to the x coordinates, but I was trying to do this using matrices. I read a lot of tutorials and articles over the subject but I couldn't find any exactly example. I want to do this using OpenGL ES and Java (android). I also want to apply it before sending the array to the GPU. I tried using Matrix.translateM, multiplyMM without success.

Comment: The vertex array is not so much a matrix as it is a list of vectors. You need to do matrix math on each vector individually. This page might help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)

Comment: @Craig I know that it is not a matrix, but it is treated like one. Just look at the Matrix.multiplyM signature. it accept two float arrays as parameters that are treated as matrices. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#multiplyMM(float[], int, float[], int, float[], int)

Comment: No it is not. It is 4 arbitrary vectors placed into a 4x4 matrix. What if it was a triangle? 3x4? What about a complex character model with 1000 vertices. You cannot transform them all with one matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Craig yes, your answer made me think about it and I realized that I have to iterate over each vector. So what I needed was multiplyMV and it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After the comments I realized that I do was thinking it wrong and that I needed to apply the matrix on each vertex like so:

```
transformationMatrix = doTransformations(4f, 2f, 4f, 4f, -60);
float[] result = new float[4];
for (int j = 0; j < 12; j += 3) {
    float[] data = new float[]{
            vertexData[j + 0],
            vertexData[j + 1],
            vertexData[j + 2],
            1};
    Matrix.multiplyMV(result, 0, transformationMatrix, 0, data, 0);
    vertexData[j + 0] = result[0];
    vertexData[j + 1] = result[1];
    vertexData[j + 2] = result[2];
}
```

and the tranformation method:

```
public static float[] doTransformations(float x, float y, float scaleX, float scaleY, float angle){
    float[] scratch = new float[16];
    float[] transformation = new float[16];
    float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(transformation,0);

    Matrix.translateM(transformation, 0, x, y ,0);
    Matrix.scaleM(transformation, 0, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, -1.0f);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0,transformation,0,mRotationMatrix,0);
    return scratch;
}
```

this is the image I was trying to transform before the matrix transformation:
[image before transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ9ml.png)

and after:
[image after transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI00w.png)